# SQL Select Command with Unicode string is not Retrieving the Expected Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I want the retrieve the row from table in which data is other than than English.

But when I type the command it returns me nothing.

```
SELECT * 
FROM PARTY 
WHERE NAME LIKE 'رانا عطا ربانی' 
ORDER BY SRNO
```

Any suggestions, how to retrieve record like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried declaring the string literal as unicode?

```
SELECT * FROM PARTY 
WHERE NAME LIKE N'رانا عطا ربانی' 
ORDER BY SRNO
```

[This will show you all string-related columns in your database, and their collation: [Collation conflict SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730982/collation-conflict-sql-server-2008) ]

Comment: Thanks Mitch.It gives me the the related record. Is there any solution to retrieve record if i type the first word and it gives me the related records like if i type 'رانا' it will gives all records related to it.