# NVARCHAR SQL type problem with Persian char

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, farsi

I have a problem in SQL with NVARCHAR type and Persian char 'ی' and 'ک', I have some records in a Table like:

```
+----- Name ------+
+----- علی ------+
```

When I want to select from this Table like:

```
select * from [Table] when Name like 'علی'
select * from [Table] when Name='علی'
select * from [Table] when Name like 'علي'
select * from [Table] when Name='علي'
```

It returns NULL! I found that when I use N before strings it is solved but I need to use N before parameter in SP and try this:

```
declare @name nvarchar(max)='علی'
select * from [Table] when Name like N''+@name
```

But unfortunately it is not working and I found when I assign 'علی' to the nvarchar, automatically 'ی' converted to 'ي'!!!

How can I fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Select Command with Unicode string is not Retrieving the Expected Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411689/sql-select-command-with-unicode-string-is-not-retrieving-the-expected-data)

Comment: See also [The 'N' in the where clause of SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18521928/1260204)

Comment: You should normalize your data to have only Persian yeh and keh and not Arabic yeh and keh. more info in Persian: https://www.dotnettips.info/post/90

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using MS SQL Server. In that case the N prefix denotes a unicode string.

Thus, you should use N'*' whenever you set a unicode string. Therefore, you should change your stored procedure like so:

```
declare @name nvarchar(max)=N'علی'
select * from [Table] when Name like @name
```

Comment: It is ok, but not things that I want, I want to give this @name parametrically from SP, it comes from C#

Answer (score 0):

1- Search and find the best `Collation` and `Unicode` for your database. It can be different in each case.

2- If you are using a programming language, you can handle it there. When you want to save a record, you should change `ی ک ه` and unify them. It means you should always use the same char. In save, update and select(in where clause).

3- You can make a trigger for `Insert` and unify characters.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use N before a parameter that is Nvarchar.
This will work :

```
declare @name nvarchar(max)='علی' -- or maybe you want  '%علی%'
select * from [Table] when Name like @name
```

Comment: No, this will not work (or, at least, it's not guaranteed to, depending on your database collation). The `N` in front of the *string* literal is still required, and that's already covered in another answer. SQL Server does not change the type of a literal based on how it's used; this implicitly converts a `VARCHAR(3)` that more likely than not consists of just `???`.